# Using 2 verbs together

Tags: verbs

Can someone tell me if the sentences below are correct?

- It allows you to **bulk create** sheets.
- It allows you to **bulk print** sheets.
- It allows you to **bulk edit** sheets.

When I write a sentence with "to bulk" + other verbs, Grammarly tells me that it's not correct. However, I see this combination widely spread and used by companies like Google, Microsoft, Jira, etc (I am giving those examples because the content I am writing is about software).

Comment: "Bulk" isn't *only* a verb.

Comment: Also "print" and "edit" are not only verbs. Are the above sentences correct?

Comment: Bulk modifies the verb but is not part of the verb. Consider 'bulk' before a verb or verb phrase to be the same as 'in bulk' after it. To bulk edit is to edit in bulk.

Comment: I think it should be bulk-print, bulk-create, bulk-edit.

Comment: @RamPillai - a hyphen is possible, but not obligatory.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, in that case, all of the sentences are correct, am I right? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: They are all OK, but if you are going to use all three sentences, one after the other, it would be better to say "It allows you you to bulk create, edit and print sheets".

Comment: Thank you once again @MichaelHarvey! No, those were just examples. Sadly, I can't upvote your comments yet. But if you want to provide an answer, I'll mark it as being the solution.